# Sapui5- Page not displayed

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to build a simple Hello World App in OpenUI5 using the proper MVC structure. I am using sap.m.App and not SplitApp. 
So my App.view.js looks like this :

```
....
createContent : function(oController) {

    this.setDisplayBlock(true);

    this.app = new sap.m.App("targetAppId", {

    });
    return this.app;
}
....
```

In my component, for routing I am wrote the following code :

```
routing : {
                config : {
                    viewType : "XML",
                    viewPath : "./view",
                    targetControl : "targetAppId",
                    clearTarget : false,
                    transition : "slide"
                },
                routes : [{
                    pattern : "",
                    viewType : "XML",
                    name : "splash",
                    view : "splash",
                    viewPath : "./view",
                    viewLevel : 0,
                }
                ]
              }
            }
```

Both my App.view.js and splash.view.xml is in ./view .

In my component.js I wrote the following code to load the view :

```
createContent : function() {
            var oView = sap.ui.view({
                id : "app",
                viewName : "./view.App",
                type : "JS",
                viewData : {
                    component : this
                }
            });
           return oView;
}
```

splash.view.xml -

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m" >
<Page
showHeader="true">
<content>
    <Text text="Hello"/>
</content>
</Page>
</mvc:View>
```

On execution I get a blank blue color screen. For some reason it is not navigating to splash.view.xml. I have no idea why. Please help.

EDIT :

If I change the sap.m.App to sap.m.SplitApp and add targetAggregation : "masterPages". Everything works

**UPDATE** :

What I did is changing the targetAggregation : "pages" . And everything works fine. Writing this here, in case it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `targetAggregation : "pages"`,  everything works fine.